# Generate tables from entities - JTA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I use the JPA tools to generate tables from `@Entity` classes. When set to `RESOURCE_LOCAL` it works just fine. However after I set up a data source on a glassfish server and modified the `persistence.xml` accordingly, it stops with an exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/mysqltest].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/mysqltest' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
...
```

Therefore each time I want to modify the table structure I need to change it back

from

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit name="Foo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/footest</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="None"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

to

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit name="Foo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="None"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Is there a way to use the table generation tool without the need of touching the config?

Answer (score 0):

Does jta-data-source name work at all?  Try fully qualifying the URL.

```
<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/footest</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The data source is working, I'm able to use the entity manager and return results from a database. I've also tried your suggestion. However the exception during the process of generating tables is still the same.